# Terraform plan giving error while trying to create Azure Service Bus subscriptions

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am planning to create three Azure service bus subscriptions belonging to a single topic. The three subscriptions will be having unique properties. So should i be doing this by dynamic blocks in Terraform?
I have my below code, but it is throwing error. Can anyone please help me fix this

```
resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "default" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  name                = module.names-servicebus-namespace.results
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "default" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.default.resource_group_name
  namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.default.name
  name                = module.names-default.environment.servicebus_topic.name_unique
  enable_partitioning = false
}



resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "new-subscr" {
  for_each            = local.svc_bus_subscr
  resource_group_name = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default.resource_group_name
  namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default.namespace_name
  topic_name          = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default.name
  name                = local.svc_bus_subscr.name.value
  requires_session    = local.svc_bus_subscr.requires_session.value
  max_delivery_count  = 5
}


locals {
  svc_bus_subscr = {
    sub-1 = {
      name             = format("sbs-%s-%s-%s", var.resource_group_name, (var.resource_group_environment != "main") ? var.resource_group_environment : "dev", "6e05")
      requires_session = false
    }
    sub-2 = {
      name             = format("sbs-%s-%s-%s", var.resource_group_name, (var.resource_group_environment != "main") ? var.resource_group_environment : "dev", "cea0")
      requires_session = true
    }
    sub-3 = {
      name             = format("sbs-%s-%s-%s", var.resource_group_name, (var.resource_group_environment != "main") ? var.resource_group_environment : "dev", "8ea5")
      requires_session = true
    }
  }
}
```

The error that i am getting is :

```
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on resources.sb.tf line 83, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "new-subscr":
│   83:   name                = local.svc_bus_subscr.name.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.svc_bus_subscr is object with 3 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "name".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on resources.sb.tf line 84, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "new-subscr":
│   84:   requires_session    = local.svc_bus_subscr.requires_session.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.svc_bus_subscr is object with 3 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "requires_session".
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `for_each`, you have to access the elements in your locals as follows:

```
 name                = local.svc_bus_subscr.value.name
 requires_session    = local.svc_bus_subscr.value.requires_session
```